# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] - Husky, lint-staged, eslint - nodeJS:

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslintrc, husky

although there were other questions about this, most were left without a response or the response given did not work for me.

For what it gives apparently eslint is looking within node_modules, here is the given error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/kamoraes/Workspace/node_adc/node_modules/supports-color/index.js from /home/kamoraes/Workspace/node_adc/.git/hooks/commit-msg not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/kamoraes/Workspace/node_adc/.git/hooks/commit-msg to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kamoraes/Workspace/node_adc/.git/hooks/commit-msg:8:23) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}


Node v16.13.0
```

The problem is, the project is in it's first steps, quickly redoing the project in another machine on the same node and yarn, version, don't give the same error. Also asked a friend of mine to try it. no error given.

also, this project is an course, same steps made, here is my entire code as for now:

> https://github.com/kaiqueAMoraes/clean-node-api

the last commit for this given error is **chore: eslintignore** 6250e5bdea05cc2eb413c8a57a97e4bbe4bd5bb9

I've added husky, lint-staged

```
yarn add -D husky lint-staged
```

then added their respectively config files

.huskyrc.json:

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  }
}
```

.lintstagedrd.json:

```
{
  "*.ts": [
    "eslint 'src/**' --fix",
    "git add"
  ]
}
```

for reference:
tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir" : "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

eslintrc:

```
{
  "extends": "standard-with-typescript",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  }
}
```

both gitignore and eslintignore ignores node_modules and dist

Comment: Hey @kamoraes! What system are you working on? windows? linux? mac?

Comment: PC Linux - fedora 34 somewhat of a fresh install, other tests were made in a Mac, both my machine and my friends machine

Comment: and it doesn't work on which of them? Linux and mac? or just one? Since you said it works on some computers but doesn't work on others, I'm pretty sure it's related to file execution permissions. try `chmod 777` your husky git-hook file inside `.husky`. That might fix the problem. If it didn't, let me know and I'll try to help further

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this @kamoraes?

Answer (score 0):

Removing lint-staged and then adding it again solved this problem for me.  This upgraded lint-staged from 12.3.5 to 14.0.1

Answer (score -5):

Ran into the same issue.
You could bypass the check with `git commit -m "your message here" --no-verify`.